# Why first coil has more copper turns?

Tags: transformer, coil

Why primary of transformer has more windings which secondary?

I measure ohm in first coil and got more ohms than in the second coil! This is a transformer downer, because I put 230v on the side and obtain 24v on the other side. I understand this, but I can't understand, on level electric, why the more copper turns in the first coil and the side where I got minus voltage I have less turns!

Thanks

Comment: Because that's how you make a step-down transformer.

Comment: Poor Michael must be rotating in his final resting place.

Comment: The ohms is not a good indicator of the turns of wire for a couple of reasons- first the gauge is generally different between primary and secondary (because the designer will try to optimize the transformer) and also the outer winding will have more length than the inner winding for the same number of turns (assuming one winding over the other, not all transformers are made this way). Fortunately, it does lead you to the correct conclusion but there is no reason I could not make a step-down transformer with higher secondary resistance than primary, by using very thin wire for the secondary.

Answer (score 3):

The primary and secondary windings share the same magnetic core and about 95% to 99% of the magnetic flux (\$\Phi\$) connects to the secondary. The small percentage loss is due to flux that leaks from the primary that doesn't connect to the secondary.

Faraday's Law of induction: -

\$V=-N\dfrac{d\Phi}{dt}\$ (induced voltage is proportional to the number of turns)

This law also applies to the creation of magnetic flux when an AC voltage is applied to the primary. So, if primary and secondary have equal turns then the voltage on the secondary will be about 97% of that applied to the primary.

If the turns ratio is step down 10:1 then the voltage on the secondary is about 97% of one-tenth of the primary voltage.

Given also that ampere turns in the loaded secondary cancel load ampere turns in the primary (easily proven), a load current of (say) 1 amp in the secondary produces about one-tenth of the load current in the primary.

Answer (score 1):

The ratio of the turns on the primary to the secondary coils of the transformer determines the voltage conversion ratio as well.

So if you have a transformer that converts 230VAC to 24VAC be aware that the primary side of the transformer has 230/24 = 9.58 times as many turns as the secondary.

Answer (score 0):

There are transformers with equal count of turns for both primary and secondary winding and voltages will be the same in this case.

A transformer to raise the voltage has less primary turns than secondary.

A transformer to lower the voltage has more primary turns than secondary.

A transformer from 120 V down to 12 V AC has 10 times of turns for primary winding than secondary winding.

But the primary and secondary windings do not necessaryly use the same wire gauge. If there are a lot of layers of windings, the total length of one turn of an inner layer is shorter than one turn of the outer layer. Therefore the number of turns is not always related to the resistance of a winding.